# Cannot find profile dependent dependency in a child pom

Tags: maven

Could anyone advice on the following:

I have parent maven xml like this:

```
<project>
...
    <modules>
        <module>Module_1</module>
    </modules>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
           <id>p1</id>
        
           <modules>
               <module>Module_2</module>
           </modules>
        <profile>
    </profiles>
...
</project>
```

And I have child pom dependent on parent one and on the Module_2 because it has beans that I want to use in my child module:

```
<project>
...
    
    <profiles>
        <profile>
           <id>p1</id>
        
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                    <groupId>some.group</groupId>
                    <artifactId>Module_2</module>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>
        <profile>
    </profiles>
...
</project>
```

So, I want Module_2 built and included as dependency into child module only with        -PModule_2 key.
But I cannot build the project because it cannot find Module_2 dependency in the child module.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Basic issue here using a module in a profile does not make sense..also looks it wrong that you have `Module_1` two times in your build one direct and one via profile?

Comment: Sorry, I've made mistake in my question. Parent pom has Module_1 and Module_2. It's need for me the Module_2 built only if I use -PModule_2 key

Comment: As I wrote using modules via profiles is the wrong way... please give more context why you are doing this ? activating a module via profile and and using a dependency via profile... this makes no sense... I don't understand your problem/idea why you are doing that?

Comment: I have swagger config that is needed to be moved into separate module by project need. And this swagger config needed to be included into the build only for specific profile. In the same time, this swagger config used by another module in the project.

Comment: Why do you use a profile? Why not building everytime ...that makes it easier?

Comment: We don't want it to build everytime because we don't wan't springfox library in the prod build